# why can't I assign properties to a new Image object?

Tags: javascript, image, properties

```
foo = new Image()
foo.x = 500
foo.x => 0
```

Comment: What is this? What errors are you getting. You need to provide a actual question! By the looks of it, I would assume that you syntax is bad!

Comment: If you tell us what you’re trying to accomplish, we might be able to help you accomplish your goal, for example by setting a `style.x` property...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var image = new Image();
image.foo = 100;
alert(image.foo);
```

works perfectly, you can't change x because it's predefined and has only a getter Method